# Compile options to suppress GCC warnings from other people's header files?

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.2

I am using these compile options in my Makefile. And my application links to several 3rd party libraries.

```
-ggdb -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c89
```

However, the pedantic is displaying many warning for the 3rd party libraries. I am wondering how can I avoid displaying these warning and still keep my compiler option pedantic.

The reason I am asking this is that the 3rd party libraries is displaying nearly 50 warning. However, I would still like to compile my source code with -pedantic.

Comment: You mean warnings for their *headers*?

Comment: you would have too enable/disable diagnostics in parts of file, I do not think g++ allows that much control. you can look at th diagnostic pragma, maybe its behavior changed

Comment: @Alok, yes its the headers that give me lots of warning. Its just annoying seeing all these warning. I cannot change the code in the headers as its part of the API that we are using. And I don't want to remove the pedantic compiler option, as I need it for compiling my own source code. Compiling gcc 4.4.2

Comment: Complain to the people supplying the headers.  Explain that you compile your code with the stringent options (and what they are) and that you expect suppliers of quality code to meet the same standards.  Until then, you will have to either tolerate the warnings or use less stringent options. Or fix the headers for them, use the fixed headers for the time being, and send the fixed headers back to them with "see - it wasn't hard to do".

Comment: Maybe, the libraries are using some C99 features like variadic macros, '//' comments, variable length arrays, etc. If so I'd first try to remove the -std=c89 option and maybe add -std=c99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the [GCC Manual on diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas) will help you.